# Hasura code generation inconsitency witl letter casing

Tags: typescript, hasura, graphql-codegen

The code generated by graphql codegen provides inconsistent letter casing. I am almost certain that something is not right in the config, or some other mistake i made. I would appreciate guidance the proper setup to fix this issue, everything else seems to work.

Only 3 constraints break in the code the 3 tables in the database, but that is enough for it not to work.

The generated code:

```
/** on_conflict condition type for table "Batch" */
export type Batch_On_Conflict = {
  constraint: Batch_constraint;
  update_columns?: Array<Batch_update_column>;
  where?: InputMaybe<Batch_Bool_Exp>;
};

/** unique or primary key constraints on table "Batch" */
export type Batch_Constraint =
/** unique or primary key constraint on columns "id" */
  | 'Batch_pkey';
```

The config:

```
overwrite: true
ignoreNoDocuments: true
schema:
  - http://localhost:8080/v1/graphql:
      headers:
        'x-hasura-admin-secret': 
documents:
  - "./src/**/*.graphql"
generates:
  ./out/sdk/batchSDK.ts:
    plugins: [
      'typescript',
      'typescript-operations',
      'typescript-react-apollo',
    ]
    config:
      preResolveTypes: true
      skipTypename: false
      withHooks: true
      withHOC: false
      withComponent: false
      enumsAsTypes: true
      constEnums: true
      decapitalizeFields: true
      namingConvention: 'change-case-all#pascalCase'
      useSemanticNaming: true,
      transformUnderscore: true
      reactApolloVersion: 3
  ./graphql.schema.json:
    plugins:
      - "introspection"
```

Please note that this config is the latest iteration, the letter casing seems to change the case properly, but neither preset fixes this particular issue pasted above.

Any thoughts?